# Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in codeigniter model

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have model query but i am getting error as Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in some of the systems and in some of the systems its working fine.Here is the query were i am getting the issues.

```
     public function getChatPlanProvidersInfoById($planId) {
    $providersArr = array();
    $this->db->select('ppm.price as plan_price, ppm.offer_start, ppm.offer_end, ppm.validity_period, pipm.provider_id, pipm.provider_group_id');
    $this->db->from('chatinstance_provider_mapping pipm');
    $this->db->join('chatplan_instance ppm', 'ppm.id = pipm.chatplan_instance_id');
    $this->db->where('pipm.chatplan_instance_id', $planId);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $providersInfo = $query->result();
        if (count($providersInfo) > 0) {
            $providersArr['offerInfo'] = array('offer_start' => $providersInfo[0]->offer_start, 'offer_end' => $providersInfo[0]->offer_end, 'valid_period' => $providersInfo[0]->validity_period);
            $providersArr['plan_price'] = $providersInfo[0]->plan_price;
            foreach ($providersInfo as $provider) {
                if (!empty($provider->provider_id)) {
                    $pInfo = $this->getProviderInfoById($provider->provider_id);
                    $providersArr['providerInfo'][] = $pInfo;
                } else if (!empty($provider->provider_group_id)) {
                    $pInfo = $this->getProviderGroupInfoById($provider->provider_group_id);
                    if (count($pInfo) > 0) {
                        $providersArr['providerInfo'][] = $pInfo;
                    } else {
                        $providersArr['providerInfo'][] = array();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $providersArr;
}
```

Getting error in this if condition count($pInfo)

```
                   if (count($pInfo) > 0) {
                        $providersArr['providerInfo'][] = $pInfo;
                    } else {
                        $providersArr['providerInfo'][] = array();
                    }
```

Comment: check value of `$pInfo` before pass to `count()`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra its working fine in all the system with xampp version 1.8.0  but when checking in client system it is getting this error.The client is using xampp 7.3.9 it is getting in that

Comment: because its different PHP version.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it work on your system is that may be you are using **PHP** version **5.6** or **< 7.2**

**As on Version 7.2** you will get warning if you pass `null` or `false` to `count()`

```
$data[5]  = 7;
var_dump(count($data)); // It will return 1


var_dump(count(null)); // It will give Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in...

var_dump(count(false)); // It will give Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in...
```

So in your case

You should check `$pInfo` before pass to `count()` as below

```
if ($pInfo && count($pInfo) > 0) {...
```

Comment: So instead of if (count($pInfo) > 0) { i need to replace the code with this if ($pInfo && count($pInfo) > 0)

Comment: thats it or anything else we need to change in that